# DAGs not loading into airflow

Tags: docker, airflow

I am just following airflow puckel and some other blog to try out airflow using docker (since I am using windows, i cannot able to pip install it) so I am using docker. I have added the code to dags folder (newtut.py)

```
dag = DAG(
'newtut',
default_args=default_args,
description='A simple tutorial DAG',
schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)
```

I have also executed these lines as a part of docker command.

```
docker pull puckel/docker-airflow
```

and then

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e LOAD_EX=y -v ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

But when I ran this, I couldnt find my dag in that list
Please advice

Comment: Look in your webserver logs, you'll see something like `{models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /var/local/airflow/dags`. That will tell you where it's reading the DAGs from and you can troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 0):

I used Local Executor to start the docker and it worked fine for me